# Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application, anyone knows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, vue.js

i wanna show list in page, but i still confuse to use componentDidMount and componentWillMount,and i got this error :
Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Articles (created by LatestNews)
    in div (created by LatestNews)
    in div (created by LatestNews)

```js
import React from 'react';
import api from '../../api/article';

class Articles extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      isMounted: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.timer = setInterval(() =>  this.setState({ isMounted: true }, () => {
        if (this.state.isMounted) {
          this.setState({ isMounted: false });
          {
            // do something
            // this.props.onClick(...)
          }
        }
      }), 5000);
    }
  

  componentWillMount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
    api.getArticles()
      .then( articles => {
        console.log(articles)
        this.setState({articles:articles.article})
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render disini')
    return (
      
      <div className="blogpost">
       {this.state.articles.map((news, i) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
          <div className="image-wrapper">
            <img className="responsive-img" src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
          </div>
          <div className="content"  key={i}>
            <h4>{news.tittle}</h4>
            <p>{news.content}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="footer">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="footer-content">
                <i className="material-icons">today</i>
                <span>{this.formatDate(news.created)}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="footer-content">
                <i className="material-icons">chat bubble outline</i>
                <a href="">6</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="read-more">
            <a href="">Read more</a>
          </div>
          </React.Fragment>
            );
          })};
      </div>
    );
  };
}
export default Articles;
```

Comment: I think this is your answer https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html

Comment: Are you removing the component in the parent component that renders `Articles`? It has most likely been unmounted before your asynchronous operations are done.